# Inverse of a normal operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space $F$.

> Assume that $S$ is invertible. Is it true that $S$ is normal iff $S^{-1}$ is normal?

If $S$ is normal then $SS^*=S^*S$ and thus $(SS^*)^{-1}=(S^*S)^{-1}$. Hence $(S^{-1})^*S^{-1}=S^{-1}(S^{-1})^*$

Comment: Yes, it is true, and yes the statements below prove the claim (or at least half of it).

Comment: @Aweygan Why the converse is true? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S^{-1}$ is normal, then 
$$(S^*S)^{-1}=S^{-1}(S^{-1})^*=(S^{-1})^*S^{-1}=(SS^*)^{-1}.$$
Thus $S^*S=SS^*$ and therefore $S$ is normal.